# Commit to github repo using node.js

Tags: node.js, github, github-pages

I am **VERY** new to git, and am trying to commit to a GitHub repo using node.js. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/hello-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use https://www.nodegit.org/

You can easily install it with `npm install nodegit`